# Why doesn't python regex search method consistently return the matched object correctly?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

I am doing a practice question on a Regex course:

How would you write a regex that matches a sentence where the first word is either Alice, Bob, or Carol; the second word is either eats, pets, or throws; the third word is apples, cats, or baseballs; and the sentence ends with a period? This regex should be case-insensitive. It must match the following:

- Alice eats apples.
- Bob pets cats.
- Carol throws baseballs.
- Alice throws Apples.
- BOB EATS CATS.

My code is as follows:

```
regex=re.compile(r'Alice|Bob|Carol\seats|pets|throws\sapples\.|cats\.|baseballs\.',re.IGNORECASE)
mo=regex.search(str)
ma=mo.group()
```

When I pass `str ='BOB EATS CATS.'` or `'Alice throws Apples.'`, `mo.group()` only returns `'Bob'` or `'Alice'` respectively, but I was expecting it to return the whole sentence.

When I pass `str='Carol throws baseballs.'`, `mo.group()` returns `'baseballs.'`, which is the last match.

I am confused as to why:

- For the first two str examples I passed, it returned the first match(`'Bob'` or `'Alice'`), whilst the 3rd str example I passed  returned the last match (`'baseball'`)?
- In all 3 str examples, I'm not sure why `mo.group()` is not returning the entire sentence as the match. i.e. i was expecting `'Carol throws baseballs.'` as output from `mo.group()`

Comment: Because you didn't group the pipes

Comment: Thanks for the comment, why do we need to group the pipes in () ? I thought grouping with parenthesis is only if we are looking for groups; i  am looking to match the entire expression.... also doesn't explain why 'baseballs.' is returned in that one example.

Comment: Because you made the period part of the option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell your regex to group the lists of options somehow, or it will naturally think it's one giant list, with some elements containing spaces. The easiest way is to use capture groups for each word:

```
regex=re.compile(r'(Alice|Bob|Carol)\s+(eats|pets|throws)\s+(apples|cats|baseballs)\.', re.IGNORECASE)
```

The trailing period shouldn't be part of an option. If you don't want to use capturing groups for some reason (it won't really affect how the match is made), you can use non-capturing groups instead. Replace `(...)` with `(?:...)`.

Your original regex was interpreted as the following set of options:

- `Alice`
- `Bob`
- `Carol\seats`
- `pets`
- `throws\sapples.`
- `cats.`
- `baseballs.`

Spaces don't magically separate options. Hopefully you can see why none of the elements of `Carol throws baseballs.` besides `baseballs.` is present in that list. Something like `Carol eats baseballs.` would match `Carol eats` though.

Comment: Thank you! initially I thought that  grouping parenthesis are not needed as I wasn't looking to group anything.... now I know that Its needed to tell Python  to 'segment' the options

Comment: I've updated my answer to fully answer both parts of your question

Comment: thanks a lot! that was eye opening around the use of \s to signify a space.  I have much to learn!

Answer (score 0):

you should group all the words

your re should look like:

```
regex = r'(?:Alice|Bob|Carol)\s(?:eats|pets|throws)\s(?:apples|cats|baseballs)\.'
```

note that i use (?:) and not (), because the grouping is only for logical purpose

Answer (score 0):

Works for all examples in the book

```
regex = r'(Alice|Bob|Carol)\s(eats|pets|trows)\s(apples|cats|baseballs)', re.I)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it like this:

```
(\w{3,5}) (\w*) ([^f]\w+)
```

Comment: I doubt that helps or even works at all. To convince me otherwise please explain how this works and why it is supposed to help.